# HTML5 video element does not play video on android device?

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am building mobile app using PhoneGap Cordova plugin. I used PhoneGap Build to build my application however when i install the apk file on my andriod mobile it would not play the below video ? I can see the player when i chick the play button it would just keep spinning ? It works on my local computer browser.

I have saved the default.mp4 video in the video folder.

Am i missing something ?

```
<video   width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="video/default.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video/default.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
  Your phone does not support video .
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android SDK lower than 4.4 you need to install a plugin for this.

Check out this plugin here:
https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer